# The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I m getting this error while making one popup for language selection
Builder is required.
also Undefined name 'Utils' in second section of code

```
  void _languageCheck() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final firstRun = prefs.getBool("firstRunLanguage");
    (firstRun ?? false)
        ? () {}
        : await showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        child: AlertDialog(content: LanguageDialog()));
    await prefs.setBool('firstRunLanguage', true);
  }
```

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late List<Widget> list = [];
  late   List<Map<String, dynamic>> languages = Utils.getLanguagesList(context);
    for (var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++) {
      // if (langCode == languages[i]["code"]) {
      //   print(languages[i]["code"]);
      // }
```

Comment: Some of the language features make no sense in the way you use them (`late` local variables, `?`/`:` instead of an `if`). You may want to become a bit more familiar with those features before you use them.

Answer (score 3):

First error is because `showDialog` has a required `builder` param, check out the documentation. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

Second error must be a missing import. Make sure you import whatever package exports `Utils`.